# React | Ant design select value not setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to add Select All / Unselect All to React Antd's 'SELECT' component.

My code

```
const models = ['A4', 'A6', 'A8', 'A1', 'Q3', 'Q5'];
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
  models: [],
});

console.log('selected', selected);

const handleModelSelect = (option) => {
  if (option === 'all') {
    if (selected.models.length === models.length) {
      setSelected((prev) => ({ ...prev, models: [] }));
    } else {
      setSelected((prev) => ({ ...prev, models }));
    }
  } else {
    setSelected((prev) => ({ ...prev, models: uniq([...prev.models, option]) }));
  }
};

return
(<Form>
  <Form.Item
    name="model"
    style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(33% - 8px)' }}
  >
    <Select mode="multiple" placeholder="Models" value={selected.models} onSelect={handleModelSelect}>
      <Option value="all">Select all</Option>
      {map(models, model => <Option value={model} key={model}>{model}</Option>)}
    </Select>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>)
```

I see that I do get everything selected & unselected in the "selected.models", however the issue is that the Select component visually does NOT update itself, meaning it stays with things I have selected/unselected.

Really weird behavior.

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe an online demo would be great for others trying to find out the problem you are facing quickly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was with using Antd's **Form & Form.item** along with **Select**.
Code works perfectly fine without the **Form**

Answer (score 2):

[Alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096447/4357871) is correct. For anyone who need **Form.item** as parent for **Select** - it is possible with [custom form components](https://medium.com/swlh/use-custom-and-third-party-react-form-components-with-ant-design-and-typescript-2732e7849aee). Just create your custom component that render antd Select. And paste your component as only child to **Form.item** (without any nested elements or wrappers)

```
<Form.Item>
    <MySelect />
</Form.Item>
```

Your custom component will automatically receive **value** and **onChange** as props. And you can also pass in additional your own props to your custom component. For example field **name** or **data** - an array of options for select.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `models` variable is unchanged. You could apply the below two changes:

**One**

```
const models = ['A4', 'A6', 'A8', 'A1', 'Q3', 'Q5'];
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
  // Initial state
  models,
});
```

**Two**

```
// Get models from `selected`
{map(selected.models, model => <Option value={model} key={model}>{model}</Option>)}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't (and didn't) work, the problem is not about the state not changing, problem is with AntDesign ignoring the the value prop, which should map to state, that is perfectly fine

Comment: Also I don't want to start with everything selected, quite the opposite I want to start with everything unselected, hence the empty array

Answer (score 1):

If you define a *name* prop on a **Form.Item**, it intercepts a *value* prop of a child component. You should use a form methods to manage a data state of the child component ([more info below a props list](https://ant.design/components/form#formitem)).
If you want use the *value* prop *don't define the name prop* on the **Form.Item**, or *don't wrap* it in a **Form** component, but in this case you can't use the form stuff like validation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).