# antd Default table design does not work with Select Options and Date Picker

Tags: reactjs, antd

The antd tables work well with Input components. I have been using the editable cell example at https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-edit-cell and it works well with undo / redo functionality.

The Select / Options and Date Picker components however do not have any documentation in the context of a table that's hooked up to a state. I have gotten the Options / Date Picker to work but when implementing undo / redo logic, it looks like their state does not by default update like the Input fields. If you Google this, it is a tricky part of React in general to get these components to update automatically with state changes in a Form.

**Is there an example of an antd table with select or date picker that's hooked up to state information?**

I got the Select / Option to work correctly visually e.g. default states load correctly, depending on selection color changes etc. I can  manipulate the data as needed. Similarly, got the Date Picker to work. However, where I am stuck is automatically tying state changes to update the components. I can probably do some crazy stuff like force render but before going that route wanted to check if there is a cleaner / better antd way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting many hours on this, it looks like there is a bug in antd Forms. See this SO thread: [React | Ant design select value not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028795/react-ant-design-select-value-not-setting)

In short, removed the Form.Item and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to custom return to default Editable Cells like the following example [url example](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-editable-antd-hpenj0?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The example does not work though - the render function also does not operate that way.